# Why using apex deploy two alias are assigned in the same version?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

I have a pipeline with this commands:
apex deploy --env prod --alias prod --region us-west-2
apex deploy --env qa --alias qa --region us-west-2
apex deploy --env dev --alias dev --region us-west-2

Every time the pipeline is executed In one lambda 2 alias (dev and qa) move on the same version.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vhPN.png)

Comment: I'm not sure about how apex works but with AWS Lambda, you can attach one version to more than one aliases.

Comment: yes. but the problem is that in one lambda apex is doing that. attaching in the same version 2 aliases (dev and qa) and I have different env variables for each alias.